lots of additional characters inside text file
I logged the session text into a text file but after opening the file with Notepad++, I saw it had lots of additional characters which seemed to be ANSI escape characters.

I search the Internet to find a way to make it more human-readable, but none of them worked at all. The copilot returned the following solutions, but each one of them returned errors:

----------in Python:------------


import re
ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\\x1B(?:[@-Z\\\\-_]|\\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
cleaned_text = ansi_escape.sub('', your_text)
print(cleaned_text)




--------------- in Linux:--------------
sed -r "s/x1b [ ([0-9] {1,2} (; [0-9] {1,2})?)?m//g" <input.txt> output.txt

------------ in Notepad++:-------------
Find: \e\[(.*?)m
Replace with: a single space character (' ')
is there any working method to make the files human readable?
